# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. while running the application

Tags: android, compiler-errors

I am using firebase for using facebook and google login in my application  and getting below error when I run my code. I tried everything on stackoverflow to resolve this. Like adding packagingoptions, including multidexEnabled to true,deleting the libs folder and whatever I could get. But these didn't work for me.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/zzf.class

here is the build.gradle file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ranjit.firebaseauthentication"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled =true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:0.4.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: change 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:0.4.4' to 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.1.1'

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, But simply restarting the Android studio worked for me without any change in the above code.